# FCC, ROHS and CE certification and compliance

Tags: fcc, ce, rohs

I have design a PCB which has Stepper driver, micro-controller, 204JHD display, MOSFETS for driving fans and TRIACS for driving heaters.There is not RF components on the PCB.

What are the criterias for makiing the PCB compliance with FCC, CE and ROHS ?
Are there any specific guidelines or rules for which i must follow to make my PCB compliance with FCC, CE and ROHS ?

Where to get the reading materials for the guidelines or rules, if any ?

Do i have to go to any institution or lab to make my PCB compliance with FCC, CE and ROHS ?

Comment: A general caution: one typically cannot make a board compliant through testing.  Testing only verifies compliance.  Making it compliant usually has to be done during design of the circuit and layout - with foreknowledge of the requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FCC part:

Since your device doesn't have any RF components, it's classified as "[unintentional radiator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintentional_radiator)" under FCC rules. Hence, you're not required to have an FCC certificate if you want to sell it. Having an FCC certificate done by an external test lab is still recommended, since it covers you in case of lawsuits to some extent.

Of course, you can study the [relevant standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_47_CFR_Part_15) to make sure your device is complying, but since you cannot self-declare FCC compliance, these are of limited use.

Answer (score 4):

I can answer part of this.

RoHS is self-declared; get the RoHS compliance statements from all your component manufacturers, keep them on file in case someone challenges you, and you can declare your product to be RoHS compliant.

CE is self-declared, but typically much more complex. Even identifying which standards you have to apply to your product takes some doing. (Simplest route is sometimes to just look at what standards a comparable product declared under.) I would strongly suggest hiring a third-party evaluation lab. I think UL does that sort of thing now, I've worked with F-Squared, and I'm sure there are many others.

I've never done FCC.